# Saving file mime type in database using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mime-types

I save file path in database with a title and short description

```
id   file   title   desctiption   date
```

here, I want to filter the table by file type
what is the best method should I use?
**method 1 :** save the file extension in a new field
**method 2 :** save the file mime type in a new field
**method 3 :** using mysql search in file name in the current file field as "%.jpg"

I think that wordpress uses method 2 , It stores the attachment mine type in posts table

Thanks and sorry for bad english

Comment: each method has it's ups and downs, it depends how often do you query the database, can you alter the insertion process, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use MIME types. They are unique for known types, and since you would put them in a different column, the database can efficient handle the queries on the MIME type. String comparision queries like `like *.jpg` can be slower.

If your use-case involves querying on file extensions, I'd suggest you to go with method 1.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend please create new field like "extend" or other, and you just search by extend, and if you want to stay your structure table, i recommend use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(file,'.',-1)`, that is better then wildcard